# Why does the Geolib package's getCenter() function return Type 'false | { longitude: number; latitude: number; }'

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, react-map-gl

As shown on the [geolib package website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolib) the geolib getCenter() function is supposed to return an object like below:

```
{ latitude: 52.516272, longitude: 13.377722 }
```

The function I have written is:

```
 const centerMap = getCenter([markerLocation, props.actualCoordinates])
```

this returns in the console log:

```
{longitude: -26.34202029125202, latitude: 56.5658246216444}
```

however when I try to console log centerMap.longitude I get this error:

```
Property 'longitude' does not exist on type 'false | { longitude: number; latitude: number; }'.
```

Property 'longitude' does not exist on type 'false'.ts(2339)

Does anyone have an idea of why it is returning more than an object, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can return `false` as you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/manuelbieh/geolib/blob/e73a00aa1bb59ed1ebbd337c5dcd30993b6e054b/src/getCenter.ts#L10)

It happens when `points` argument is not an array or it's an empty array

Seems like they didn't bother to include that in the example

You can try checking it it's not falsy

```
const centerMap = getCenter([markerLocation, props.actualCoordinates])
if (!centerMap) {
  throw new Error('points is an empty array')
}
centerMap.longitude // will work here
```

or

```
const centerMap = getCenter([markerLocation, props.actualCoordinates])
if (centerMap) {
  centerMap.longitude // will work here
}
```

or you can cast

```
const centerMap = getCenter([markerLocation, props.actualCoordinates]) as { longitude: number; latitude: number; }
```

But I fill like the library should throw an error instead of returning false in such cases